# Can not call the function Aggregate - Multicall2.sol on BSC testnet

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I already deployed the multicall2.sol smart contract on BSC Testnet
https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x8F3273Fb89B075b1645095ABaC6ed17B2d4Bc576#code
then call the contract by using the following typescript code:

```
  try {
    const multi = getMulticallContract(options.web3 || web3NoAccount)
    const itf = new Interface(abi)

    const calldata = calls.map((call) => [call.address.toLowerCase(), itf.encodeFunctionData(call.name, call.params)])
    const { returnData } = await multi.methods.aggregate(calldata).call(undefined, options.blockNumber)
    const res = returnData.map((call, i) => itf.decodeFunctionResult(calls[i].name, call))

    return res
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error)
  }
}
```

I got the error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Returned error: execution reverted: Multicall aggregate: call failed

It's weird. Because the function works properly on Mainnet. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you specify the input data (in your case the value of `calls`)?

Comment: Hi @PetrHejda ,
Here is the input data that I used. 
```console.error(calldata)
0: Array [ "0xa35062141fa33bca92ce69fed37d0e8908868aae", "0x70a082310000000000000000000000003ed8936cafdf85cfdba29fbe5940a5b0524824f4" ]
1: Array [ "0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd", "0x70a082310000000000000000000000003ed8936cafdf85cfdba29fbe5940a5b0524824f4" ]
2: Array [ "0x3ed8936cafdf85cfdba29fbe5940a5b0524824f4", "0x70a082310000000000000000000000001d32c2945c8fdcbc7156c553b7cea4325a17f4f9" ]
3: Array [ "0x3ed8936cafdf85cfdba29fbe5940a5b0524824f4", "0x18160ddd" ]```

Comment: I found the reason. Thanks

Comment: @VietNguyen can you explain the reason?  I am dealing with the same

Comment: @DanielSon the main reason is the contracts(ex: 0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd) doesn't exist on Testnet. If you fork the PancakeSwap Mainnet Source then run on Testnet. You have to remove/replace all contract Tokens and LP in the configuration file

Answer (score 0):

The author found his solution but just to complete the troubleshooting I suggest making sure you have:

- Have the contract deployed on testnet
- Switch your RPC Node Url to the correct network. For example: BSC testnet's is https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i resolved the issue by simply switching the rpc from https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s3.binance.org:8545/ to https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545/

looks like they have some substantial inconsistency between nodes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).